# Express - set routes in one routes

Tags: javascript, node.js

index.js

```
app.use('/',wowYeah);
app.use('/lol',wow);
```

how to use only

routes.js

```
app.use('/',wowYeah);
app.use('/lol',wow);

app.use(routes());
```

but it can't

how to do it?

1 app use for all routes

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// birds.js file
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

```
// index.js file
const birds = require('./birds')

// ...

app.use(birds)
```

for more look [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Comment: you are the only genius here!

Comment: @MuhammadFauzan Thanks dear. but I just copy this example from official site.